# How to translate the plane towards the point for X distance?

Tags: c#, xna, translation, plane

- I got a `Plane` (Normal, d) and a `Vector3` point (x, y, z).
- I need to translate the plane to that point for X distance. How do I do that?

I'm coming up with this..

```
plane = Plane.Transform(plane, Matrix.CreateTranslation(
```

But can't figure what to place there. It has to be something with dot product, `Plane.Normal` and my `Vector3`.

**EDIT:**

I'm thinking of this.

```
public static Plane MoveTo(this Plane p, Vector3 point, float distance)
{
    Vector3 planeVector = p.Normal * p.D;

    Matrix matrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Vector3.Normalize(planeVector)) *
        distance * Math.Sign(Vector3.Dot(planeVector, point - planeVector))

    return Plane.Transform(p, matrix);
}
```

If someone considers this as wrong or particually wrong, please, note it.

Comment: Have you check MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb281689(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @hamad No I didn't but I use the same methods. I just need an approach.

Comment: So would it work for you? Create a new matrix and pass it to Plane.Transform()

Comment: @hamad I can't figure what parameters to pass to the matrix creation method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance from a point P to the plane Pi is:

[image]

[image]

You should calc current d(P, pi), substract to that the amount X, and then only have to calculate D to get the new plane.

EDIT:

```
 // This line has no sense... is useless do that.
 Vector3 planeVector = p.Normal * p.D;
```

To know the relation between a point and a plane, you only have to calculate its equation:  R = Ax + By + Cz + D where (A,B,C) is the normal and (x,y,z) the point...

if (R == 0) the point is contained in the plane
   if (R>0) the point is front    // or viceversa
   if (R<0)  that point is back

```
R = plane.DotCoordinate(point);    
distance*=(R>0) ? 1 : -1; // or viceversa, i'm not sure now
Matrix matrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(plane.Normal * distance);
return Plane.Transform(p, matrix);
```

Comment: I already have a distance from point to plane by the way (by a dot product). I need a `Vector3`-translator. The value i can use for plane matrix translation.

Comment: Just.. subtract from D or add to it?

Comment: if initial distance d(P,pi) is 100, and you want to translate 10 units towards the point, the new distance will be 100-10 = 90... then you only have to calculate "D" knowing that d(P,pi) == 90.

Comment: So how to detect is it towards or backwards? See my edit, is it right?

Comment: Do not substract the planevector to point, should be Matrix matrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Vector3.Normalize(planeVector)) *
        distance * Math.Sign(Vector3.Dot(planeVector, point)), I've not tested it, but I think that you will need to negate the sign, (... * -Math.Sign(....) ...)

Comment: I have just tested it. The subtraction is neccessary though. Thanks anyways!